# How to write a compacted card deck generator?

Tags: ruby

I am writing a card deck generator, here is the solution I come up with, but I found it spans multiple lines and doesn't look good, is there any other way to build this card?

```
deck = []
'23456789TJQKA'.each_char do |rank|
  'SHDC'.each_char do |suit|
    deck << rank + suit
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Array#product` to produce Cartesian product from two arrays.

```rb
# ruby 2.0
deck = '23456789TJQKA'.chars.product('SHDC'.chars).map{|a| a.join}

# ruby 1.9
deck = '23456789TJQKA'.split(//).product('SHDC'.split(//)).map{|a| a.join}
```

As **DNNX** commented, you can use `.map(&:join)` to get a shorter one.

However, I think it's better to write a clear program than a compact one.

Comment: You have to call `.to_a` after `.chars` if you want this code to work.

Comment: Also, .map(&:join) would be a bit shorter :)

Comment: @DNNX I forget to use the `&:symbol` notation many times :-(. Thanks.

Comment: That's really elegant! Thanks for both of you.

Answer (score 0):

As an example of using a block variant `product(other_ary, ...) { |p| block }`

```
deck = []
'23456789TJQKA'.split('').product('SHDC'.split('')){|el| deck << el.join}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Arie suggested, it's better to write a clear program than a shorter one. I think this one is dead simple:

```
deck = %w(2S 2H 2D 2C
          3S 3H 3D 3C
          4S 4H 4D 4C
          5S 5H 5D 5C
          6S 6H 6D 6C
          7S 7H 7D 7C
          8S 8H 8D 8C
          9S 9H 9D 9C
          TS TH TD TC
          JS JH JD JC
          QS QH QD QC
          KS KH KD KC
          AS AH AD AC)
```

*Just kidding.*